# Python returns NaN value list as column values

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I want to read a column from excel file using pandas in python. But it returns NaN list.

[This is the code I used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhVjo.png)

```
from pandas import DataFrame

import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel (r'D:\Pandas\1 (179).xlsx')

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['Type','callsign'])

print (df)
```

[It gives me a output like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbzBX.png)

```
     Type  callsign
0     NaN       NaN
1     NaN       NaN
2     NaN       NaN
3     NaN       NaN
4     NaN       NaN
5     NaN       NaN
6     NaN       NaN
7     NaN       NaN
8     NaN       NaN
9     NaN       NaN
10    NaN       NaN
11    NaN       NaN
12    NaN       NaN
13    NaN       NaN
14    NaN       NaN
15    NaN       NaN
```

I expect the values from excel sheet as outputs.. [Excel Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFx2G.png)

Comment: You just need `df = pd.read_excel (r'D:\Pandas\1 (179).xlsx')`

Comment: `NaN` stands for `Not a Number`, so I'd try read in as text first to see if that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your excel file does not start with the first line, there are several description in it before.

You need to skip some rows:

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'D:\Pandas\1 (179).xlsx',skiprows=5)
```

see the documentation for more adjustments: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: if this is a solution to question, you can mark it is correct, this will close the topic and other users do not spend effort on that question